# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call in Python

Tags: python, syntax-error, assignment-operator

I have :

```
a=['ab',200] 
cap_init=150
```

I actually want to update the value of my variable `a[1]` under some condition. The program can't run this instruction:

```
int(a[1])=int(a[1])-self.cap_init
```

It gives this error :

> "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"

Comment: You can't use `int(something)=` (that's a function call!), just do `something=`. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform `int(a[1])`, it just shows the integer format of `a[1]`. In python `int()` is a method to type-cast a numeric value to integer. When you are trying to do `int(a[1])=...` you are trying to first calculate the value `int(a[1]) - self.capacite_int` and then trying to assign this value to the function call of `int()` on the left side. If you want to change the value of `a[1]`, you need to reassign it simply like this :

```
a[1] = int(a[1]) - self.cap_init
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that a is already a list not tuple . and in both cases it doesn't work !